# How to have my iPad use Win 2008 server's internet connection?

Tags: ipad, windows, wifi, network

I have an iPad that is connected to my network's wireless router. However, this router is connected to my Win 2008 server, which is itself connected to the internet. The iPad is unable to connect to the public url for the exchange server on the server and has erratic internet access, where Windows laptops are provided with faultless internet access, even when they are not a member of the domain.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a dns issue to me.  You'll want to have an internal dns server that knows to route *.example.com to your server's internal address and forward everything else to a public dns server like 8.8.8.8, and make sure your dhcp service hands out this dns server.

It could also be an ipv6 issue, as Apple products are configured to very strongly prefer ipv6 whenever they can.  If you have partial ipv6 support somewhere on your network (very possible to have without even knowning) it could be confusing the iPad.

Comment: Somewhat lazy I changed the IP settings from DHCP to static and set the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 That solved it.